# Вопрос по js создание объектов и обращение к их свойствам

Tags: javascript

```
   class Unit {
constructor(i1, i2){
     _id1 = i1;
     _id2 = i2;
}}


let unit = new Unit(1, 2)
console.log(unit._id1)
```

Не могу достучаться до _id1 пишет is not defined, только начал учить js запускаю командой node units.js

```
_id1 = i1;
     ^
```

Comment: `this._id1 = i1;`

Comment: спасибо) думал this можно опустить.

Comment: 'console.log(unit.item.forEach(it => console.log(it)))' пробую на выходе получается 
'Item { id: 1 }
Item { id: 2 }
Item { id: 3 }
undefined
'
откуда беретcя undefined?

Comment: что такое `item`?

Comment: item массив объявляю в конструкторе this.item = [new Item(1), new Item(2), new Item(3)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
class Unit {
  constructor(i1, i2) {
    this._id1 = i1;
    this._id2 = i2;
  }
}


let unit = new Unit(1, 2);
console.log(unit);
```